# WP User Tagging Possible for Gamification and Event Tracking?

Tags: multisite-user-management

I am creating a networking platform with WP multisite. The client is wanting to have users login/register with FaceBook's social login app.

The more difficult request is now that users are logged in the client wants users to be able to interact with buttons that disappear - only to the individual user - once they've been clicked (kind of like little gamified easter eggs)(also he wants them to be trackable)(the man has a vision).

In the past, I was able to do something similar with InfusionSoft CRM and its WP wingman - `Memberium Membership plugin`. Where a nearly unlimited number of "Tags" could be assigned to logged in users whenever they clicked on so-called "action_links" (a tags where href="[shortcode]" then fired off an IFSoft action set that would bestow sparkling little tags on all the users, BUT in its databases that the `Memberium WP plugin` just referred to - not WP.

Now I've left automated Eden and am looking for a more native, down-home (cheap) WordPress solution. Admittedly I'd definitely appreciate anyone who knew how to handle this with shortcodes, but regardless I can put in the time as necessary. What do you guys think? Can you point me down a trail with some rainbows and a few butterflies?

Comment: what append when the user click on a button ?

Comment: Welcome to WordPress StackExchange DonChi. You're describing a detailed system with multiple components. A broad question like this may limit the usefulness of the answers you get. They'll also be broad and lack detail. I'd suggest focusing your questions on a specific problem and providing code snippets or links to things you've tried already and the results you got.

Comment: You're right. I have added a much more specific question here.

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/291055/how-to-apply-unique-post-id-as-user-meta-data